# Call method inside the super class when there is another super class exist

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, superclass

For the following code in Java, and I run it with `Person u = new Undergrad();
u.method1();` .

If I want to call the method2 within the Student class instead of the method2 in the Undergrad class, how should I alter the method1 in the Student class to call the method2 within the same class?

```
public class Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Person 1 ");
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Person 2 ");
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Student 1 ");
        super.method1();
        method2();
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Student 2 ");
    }
}


public class Undergrad extends Student {
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Undergrad 2 ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is indeed a duplication of an old question, thanks to @Sotirios who pointed it out.